# Pre-decrement of value in a for loop is not correctly decreasing value on first loop

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I have the following for loop in my code (using C#)

```
for (int i = 150; i >= 75; --i)
{
    print("I holds " + i);
    images[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

trying to run through each item in a list, and disable the object. The list holds 150 objects (but since it starts at value zero, the final reference position is 149)

So, I figured a for loop was a good way to iterate through them all. Yet, I try to decrease the value of i to 149 for the first run of the loop, but it still passes a value of 150 into the loop in the first run, which throws the expected ("Argument is out of range") error.

Can anyone work out why the decreased value isn't correctly being passed to the loop?

I tried both decreasing it before and after the first run of the loop, but both times it passes a value of 150 into the loop.

I feel this should be a relatively simple issue to solve, yet it's not working as I expected it to do!

Comment: `for (int i = 150); i >= 75; --i)`, why is there a closing bracket in the start? should it not be for `(int i = 150; i >= 75; --i)`

Comment: also if you want a value of `i = 149` to start with, why are you setting it to `150`?

Comment: apologies, I misplaced the bracket when formatting the code. I ideally set it to 150 as that is the returned images.count value - I'm trying to make it dynamic so it isn't hard coded to a set value, but obviously while images.count registers 150, there are only 149 references stored in the list. I had tried doing "for int i - images.count -1; but it feels a bit of a hack to the issue.

Comment: The decrement operation does not occur before the loop contents. `for(a; b; c) { d }` runs in the order: a, b, d, c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to loop through all items of an array without caring of actual indices is to make use of a `foreach` statement:

```
foreach(var image in images)
{
    image.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

If you want to use a `for` statement. I would suggest you write it as below:

```
for(var i=0; i<images.Length; i++)
{ 
    image[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Doing so, you are pretty confident that you are not going to be out of the array's size. You start at the element at the position with index of 0 and you read the last item stored in the array, in the position of `images.Length-1`.

**Update**
If you want to update only the first 75 items (where 75 is half the total items in the array) in your array you could try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<images.Length/2; i++)
{ 
    image[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response - so, I'm trying to iterate through only half the objects in the list and disable them - passing "images.length" wouldn't work as I only need to disable the first 75 objects.

Comment: @Volks `images.Length/2` then

Comment: @Volks You are welcome. Please check my update. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 0; --i)
```

is the same as

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
```

`i` does not decrease/increase on the first loop. This is for many languages. Just start with 149 and it works.

Answer for "Can anyone work out why the decreased value isn't correctly being passed to the loop?"